# Pandas: Apply pytz.FixedOffset to a Series

Tags: python, pandas, pytz

I have a DataFrame with a `timestamp` column which looks like this:

```
0     2020-01-26 05:00:00-08:00
1     2020-01-26 06:00:00-08:00
[...]
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-480)]
```

(The timestamp is not the DataFrame's index)

I would like to have that `pytz.FixedOffset(-480)` applied (or rather un-applied) to the column, so that it would look like this:

```
0     2020-01-26 13:00:00
1     2020-01-26 14:00:00
[...]
```

How can I achieve this without parsing `timestamp` manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_convert(None)
print (df)
            timestamp
0 2020-01-26 13:00:00
1 2020-01-26 14:00:00
```

Comment: I've come across this function, but somehow I missed the option to pass `None` as the `tz` argument. Thanks!